# Why is .loc slicing in pandas inclusive of stop, contrary to typical python slicing?

Tags: python, pandas

I am slicing a pandas dataframe and I seem to be getting unexpected slices using `.loc`, at least as compared to numpy and ordinary python slicing. See the example below.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[9,10,11],[34,2,1]])
>>> a
    0   1   2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   4   5   6
3   9  10  11
4  34   2   1
>>> a.loc[1:3, :]
   0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  4   5   6
3  9  10  11
>>> a.values[1:3, :]
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Interestingly, this only happens with `.loc`, not `.iloc`.

```
>>> a.iloc[1:3, :]
   0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  4  5  6
```

Thus, `.loc` appears to be inclusive of the terminating index, but numpy and `.iloc` are not.

By the comments, it seems this is not a bug and we are well warned. But why is it the case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember `.loc` is **primarily** label based indexing. The decision to include the stop endpoint becomes far more obvious when working with a non-RangeIndex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], index=list('achz'))
#   0
#a  1
#c  2
#h  3
#z  4
```

If I want to select all rows between `'a'` and `'h'` (inclusive) I only know about `'a'` and `'h'`. In order to be consistent with other python slicing, you'd need to also know what index follows `'h'`, which in this case is `'z'`  but could have been anything.

---

There's also a section of the documents hidden away that explains this design choice [Endpoints are Inclusive](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#endpoints-are-inclusive)

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to the point in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), `pandas` slice indexing using `.loc` is **not cell index** based. It is in fact **value based indexing** (in the pandas docs it is called "label based", but for numerical data I prefer the term "value based"), whereas with `.iloc` it is traditional numpy-style cell indexing.

Furthermore, value based indexing is right-inclusive, whereas cell indexing is not. Just try the following:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[9,10,11],[34,2,1]])
a.index = [0, 1, 2, 3.1, 4]  # add a float index

# value based slicing: the following will output all value up to the slice value
a.loc[1:3.1]
# Out:
# 0    1   2
# 1.0  3   4   5
# 2.0  4   5   6
# 3.1  9  10  11

# index based slicing: will raise an error, since only integers are allowed
a.iloc[1:3.1]
# Out: TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Float64Index'> with these indexers [3.2] of <class 'float'>
```

To give an explicit answer to your question why it is right-inclusive:
When using values/labels as indices, it is, at least in my opinion, intuitive, that the last index is included. This is as far as I know a design decision of how the implemented function is meant to work.

Comment: I assume that value-based indexing was chosen to be right-inclusive because it allows the user to pass a list/iterable of valid indices when making a selection. That's how I often use it.

Comment: @SNygard Yes, I guess so. Imho for value based indexing right-inclusive is the most "familiar" behavior.

Comment: Agreed. Value-based indexing allows users to `a.loc[[0,2]]` and also perform slicing.