# Selecting specific rows from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to know if there is any function in pandas that selects specific rows based on index from a dataframe without having to write your own function.

For example: selecting rows with index [15:50] from a large dataframe.

I have written this function, but I would like to know if there is a shortcut.

```
def split_concat(data , first , last):
    data_out = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(first, last +1):
        data_split = data.loc[i]
        data_out = pd.concat([data_out,data_split],axis = 0)

    return data_out
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use either `pandas.DataFrame.loc` or `pandas.DataFrame.iloc`. See examples below.

```
import pandas as pd

d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
     {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},
     {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 },
     {'a': 1500, 'b': 2500, 'c': 3500, 'd': 4500}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)               # Print original dataframe
print(df.loc[1:2])      # Print rows with index 1 and 2, (method 1)
print(df.iloc[1:3])     # Print rows with index 1 and 2, (method 2)
```

Original dataframe: `print(df)` will print:

```
      a     b     c     d
0     1     2     3     4
1   100   200   300   400
2  1000  2000  3000  4000
3  1500  2500  3500  4500
```

And `print(df.loc[1:2])` for index selection by label:

```
      a     b     c     d
1   100   200   300   400
2  1000  2000  3000  4000
```

And `print(df.iloc[1:3])` for row selection by integer. As mentioned by ALollz, rows are treated as numbers from 0 to `len(df)`:

```
      a     b     c     d
1   100   200   300   400
2  1000  2000  3000  4000
```

A rule of thumb could be:

- Use `.loc` when you want to refer to the actual value of the index, being a string or integer.
- Use `.iloc` when you want to refer to the underlying row number which always ranges from 0 to `len(df)`.

Note that the *end* value of the slice in `.loc` is included. This is not the case for `.iloc`, and for Python slices in general.

**Pandas in general**

Pandas has 'easy' ways of doing all sorts of stuff like this. If you have a problem that you think is common for manipulation of tabular data, try searching for pandas ways of getting it done before inventing it yourself. Pandas will almost always have a syntactically concise and computationally faster way of doing things than what we can write ourselves.

Comment: In general `.iloc` doesn't behave how you describe; it only does in this case where you have a rangeIndex that starts from 0. `.iloc` will index the underlying array by the array indices (starting from 0 running to `len(df)`). These need not have any relation to the real index of the DataFrame. For instance, see the output of `pd.DataFrame(['A','B','C'], index=[7,8,9]).iloc[0:2]`. This post also gives a good explanation as to why `.loc` is end-inclusive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187559/why-is-loc-slicing-in-pandas-inclusive-of-stop-contrary-to-typical-python-slic

Comment: You are right ALollz. It refers to the underlying row number ranging from 0 to `len(df)`. Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
rowData = your_df.loc[ 'index' , : ]
```