# use spesific rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {   
            "day":     ["monday", "monday","Tuesday" ],
            "column0": ["xx",      "xx",     ""],
            "column1": ["yy",      "aa",    "bb"],
            "column2": ["cc",      "cc",    "cc"],
            "column3": ["cc",      "",      "aa"]})
    
    
        day    column0  column1 column2 column3
    0   monday  xx       yy       cc      cc
    1   monday  xx       aa       cc    
    2   Tuesday          bb       cc      aa
```

I want to save load and use only the second index as input to an algorithm

Expected outcome:

```
2   Tuesday          bb       cc      aa
```

i tried df1.head([2:2].to_csv("xx.csv")`

However head does not allow indexing

Any ideas?

Comment: `df.loc[1,:]` will do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting specific rows from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883053/selecting-specific-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @wwnde `df.loc[1]` is simpler