# Retrieving index based data from Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

1. ```
   data[1:3]
   1    0.50
   2    0.75
   dtype: float64
   ```

Here, i am getting two rows.

2.

```
data = pd.Series([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0],
index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
data['b':'d']
b    0.50
c    0.75
d    1.00
dtype: float64
```

Why, in the explicit indexing i am getting three rows?

I was going through loc and iloc, but not understanding.

Comment: label based slicing is **inclusive** in Pandas. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187559) and also the official docs [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting different numbers of rows when using different indexing methods is due to how they handle slicing.

When you use `data[1:3]`, it refers to the positional index (like iloc) rather than the labels. So it selects the elements at positions 1 and 2 (3 not included), resulting in two rows.

On the other hand, when you use `data['b':'d']`, it behave like loc, which considers the labels themselves. It includes the elements from the label 'b' to the label 'd', resulting in three rows.

Comment: Yes, understood it well now, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas numeric indexing mimics python indexing: `[i:j]` returns indices i through j-1, just like `iloc[]`. When you have an index that is a character, you cannot subtract a character to get the previous character. Consider the following index:

```
data  = pd.Series([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 2.0],
index = ['a', 'z', 'r', 'q', 'q'])
data['a':'q']
```

Should it stop at 'r' or 'q'? The most logical solution is to assume you're trying to access it like `.loc[]`. Thus, `data['start':'end']` will behave like `.loc[]`, and `data[i:j]` will behave like `.iloc[]`.

Comment: And it will stop at first 'q'? because that's the first 'q' it detected.

Comment: It will include all values of 'q' since they're both a part of the index.

Comment: Oh okay, understood.